# Run Kubernetes in a docker container in GitLab runner?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to be able to execute some Python code that would:

1. Run a docker container in GitLab runner.
2. Install Kubernetes (Minikube?) in that container.
3. Run a pod in that Kubernetes.

I was having troubles finding the way to run Kubernetes in a container. It shouldn't be anything advanced, just for test purposes.

Comment: Are you looking for [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) instead of Minikube. These articles may help you.

- https://adamrushuk.github.io/running-kind-in-gitlab-ci-on-kubernetes/
- https://gist.github.com/trondhindenes/0307fbe9cda1164115353b4632a31ea9